# How Can I Change Start Page of Android Studio for LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I create a game with LibGDX and I made a main menu for it but I can't do start page this main menu. How Can I do it? Can you help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpNZA.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want to make the main menu as an activity? You can render a GUI in libGDX too. With that said, you can make a main menu with libGDX directly and don't have to bother yourself with changing activities and so on. If you don't know yet about Scene2D you can read about it  [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Answer (score 0):

You see that

```
<intent-filter>
  <action ...
  <action ...
</intent-filter>
```

part of code? That code controls which one of your activities will be the launching/main activity. Just cut that intent filter and paste it inside of your AndroidLauncher activity tag (which I pressume is your menu).